# decreasing time it takes to run my program in c

Tags: c, time, malloc, realloc

I was writing a program that is reading from a file and then storing the data in two tables that are in a table of structure. I am expanding the tables with realloc and the time my program takes to run is ~ 0.7 s.

Can i somehow decrease this time?

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int *node;
    int l;
    int *waga;
} przejscie_t;

void czytaj(przejscie_t **graf, int vp, int vk, int waga) {
    (*graf)[vp].node[(*graf)[vp].l - 1] = vk;
    (*graf)[vp].waga[(*graf)[vp].l - 1] = waga;
    (*graf)[vp].l++;
}

void wypisz(przejscie_t *graf, int i) {
    printf("i=%d  l=%d ", i, graf[i].l);

    for (int j = 0; j < (graf[i].l - 1); j++) {
        printf("vk=%d waga=%d ", graf[i].node[j], graf[i].waga[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void init(przejscie_t **graf, int vp, int n) {
    *graf = realloc(*graf, (vp + 1) * sizeof(przejscie_t));
    
    if (n == vp || n == -1){
        (*graf)[vp].l = 1;
        (*graf)[vp].node = malloc((*graf)[vp].l * sizeof(int));
        (*graf)[vp].waga = malloc((*graf)[vp].l * sizeof(int));
    }
    else {
        for (int i = n; i <= vp; i++) {
            (*graf)[i].l = 1;
            (*graf)[i].node = malloc((*graf)[i].l * sizeof(int));
            (*graf)[i].waga = malloc((*graf)[i].l * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some suggestions:

1. I think you should pre-calculate the required size of your `*graf` memory instead of reallocating it again and again. By using a `prealloc_graf` function for example.

   - You will get some great time improvement since reallocating is time-consuming especially when it must actually move the memory.
   - You should do this method especially if you are working with big files.
   - And since you're working with files, pre-calculating should be done easily.

> If your files size are both light and heavy, you have two choices:
>
> 1. Accept your fate and allow your code to be a little bit less optimized on small files.
> 2. Create two `init` functions: The first one is optimized for small files, the other one will be for bigger files but... You will have to run some benchmarks to actually determine what algorithm is the best for each case before being able to implement it. You could actually automate that if you have the time and the will to do so.

2. It is important to check for successful memory allocation before trying to use the said memory because allocation function can [fail](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc#Return_value).
3. Finally, some changes for the `init` function :

```cpp
void init(przejscie_t **graf, int vp, int n) {
    *graf = realloc(*graf, (vp + 1) * sizeof(przejscie_t));
    
    // The `if` statement was redundant.
    // Added a ternary operator for ``n == -1``.
    // Alternatively, you could use ``n = (n == -1 ? vp : n)`` right before the loop.
    for (int i = (n == -1 ? vp : n); i <= vp; i++) {
        (*graf)[i].l = 1;
        // (*graf)[X].l is is always 1.
        // There is no reason to use (*graf)[X].l * sizeof(int) for malloc.
        (*graf)[i].node = malloc(sizeof(int));
        (*graf)[i].waga = malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

I've commented everything that I've changed but here is a summary :

- The `if` statement was redundant.

  - The `for` loop cover all cases with ternary operator for `n`
    equals `-1`.
  - The code should be easier to understand and to comprehend this way.
- The `node` and `waga` arrays were not being initialized "properly".
  Since `l` is always equals `1` there was no need for an
  additional operation.
  This doesn't really change execution time tho since its constant.

4. I would also suggest that your "functions running allocation functions" should return a boolean saying if the function succeeded. In the case the allocation failed you can return false to say that your function failed.